# Changes in WinRT ControlTemplate in Win8 RC

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I had the following template that essentially changed the color of the border of a button based on its pressed state:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Name="SkillIconTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" Margin="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.05"/>
                        <VisualTransition To="Pressed" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.05"/>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                                                    To="Yellow" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                    To="Black"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBrush" Color="White"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Now, it doesn't seem to work in Win8 RC. In Consumer Preview it did the following:

```
Normal State: White
Hovered State: Yellow
Pressed State: Black
```

Now it does:

```
Normal State: White
Hovered State (Before Pressed): White
Hovered State (After Pressed): Black
Pressed State: Black
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the set of defined visual states has been changed, use PointerOver instead of MouseOver.
The most of changes from Consumer Preview listed in here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251943